# Parse Name to format of "Lastname,FI" Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with names in the format of "Doe, John" and I need to parse that to "Doe, J". I already have a query written to extract just the last name, but I'm not sure how to modify it to include the comma and first initial.

```
SUBSTR(Table.Name,1,INSTR(Table.Name,',',1,1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combinations of `NVL`, `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`.

```
SELECT NVL(SUBSTR("namefield", 0, INSTR("namefield", ',')+2), "namefield") AS Name
FROM yourtable
```

Input

```
Doe, John
Smith, Mark
```

Output

```
NAME
Doe, J
Smith, M
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e1f467/7/0

Comment: You should not need double quotes around identifiers. It enforces case-sensitivity which can lead to problems when the incorrect case is used.

Comment: @MT0 their field name isnt actually called `namefield` they can rename as they see fit, the logic is still the same, but yeh i agree with no double quotes :)

Comment: @RonL Only if your results ever contain `NULL`s

Comment: @RonL No, the substring will only be `NULL` when the `namefield` is `NULL` and then you would have `NVL( NULL, NULL )` - also the second argument of `SUBSTR` should be 1 (since the character positions are 1-indexed not 0-indexed).

Answer (score 1):

What about this -

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Table.Name,1,INSTR(Table.Name,',',1)+2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The regexp_replace version, as long as there is only one space in the string as per your example data:

```
select regexp_replace('Doe, John', '(.* .).*', '\1')
```

The \1 refers to the matched part of the string in parenthesis, which is all of the string up to and including the last space and the character after it, ignoring the rest.